# In a customer records log, how can I find the latest timestamp for nonunique identifier combinations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with SSMS to query a SQL server database, with the intention of using a history table to identify the latest status of a relationship between two types of entities, e.g. customers with tiered subscriptions to various magazines (not subscribed, basic subscription, premium subscription). The history table provides the customer ID, magazine ID, a change timestamp, the old subscription value and the new subscription value. For each unique combination of customer and magazine ID, I want to take the newest timestamp and look at the newest value. The final step will be to count how many customers are subscribed to each magazine, where I am not interested in differentiating between basic and premium subscription. The problem is that if a user switches between the basic and premium subscription, my current script counts both changes and causes duplicates which artificially inflates the subscription count.

I am able to see the raw data and manually manipulate it into the format that I want, so I am happy with the data. I have tried to look at the maximum 'changed_time' for each customer, filtered to only the two basic and premium subscription and group it by the customer ID and magazine ID and new subscription status. As mentioned, this causes duplicates:

```
SELECT MAX(CHANGED_TIME), CUSTOMER_ID, MAGAZINE_ID, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE
FROM CUSTOMER_HISTORY
WHERE (NEW_VALUE=3 or NEW_VALUE=43) 

/* 0 = unsubscribed, 3 = basic subscription, 43 = premium */

GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, MAGAZINE_ID, NEW_VALUE
```

```
| Time of change | Customer ID | Magazine ID | Old Value | New Value |
|----------------|-------------|-------------|-----------| --------- |
|     today      |       a     |      1      |      3    |     43    |
|   last week    |       a     |      2      |      0    |     3     |
|     today      |       b     |      1      |      43   |     3     |
|   last week    |       b     |      2      |      0    |     3     |
|     today      |       b     |      2      |      3    |     43    |
```

I would like to build some logic that says 'for each unique combination of customer and magazine ID, return the latest new value and time of change', or in this example 'for customer b and magazine 2, only return the newest value'. This would result in the penultimate row being removed from the result, where customer b subscribed to magazine 2 - this is redundant because they then upgraded to a premium subscription for this magazine today.

The bit I am unsure on is how to identify unique combinations of the two ID types. Reading around I think a nested select from my current result will be the way forward, but I am new to SQL and can't get my head around it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the latest time of change for each unique combination of Customer ID and Magazine ID.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, MAGAZINE_ID, MAX(CHANGED_TIME) AS [CHANGE_TIME] FROM CUSTOMER_HISTORY
    WHERE (NEW_VALUE = 3) OR (NEW_VALUE = 4)
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, MAGAZINE_ID
```

Then, add a sub-query or use the query above and join it the the CUSTOMER_HISTORY table to get the NEW_VALUE columns.

```
SELECT A.CUSTOMER_ID, A.MAGAZINE_ID, A.CHANGE_TIME, B.NEW_VALUE
    FROM (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, MAGAZINE_ID, MAX(CHANGED_TIME) AS [CHANGE_TIME] FROM CUSTOMER_HISTORY WHERE (NEW_VALUE = 3) OR (NEW_VALUE = 4) GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, MAGAZINE_ID) AS A
        INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_HISTORY AS B
            ON A.CUSTOMER_ID = B.CUSTOMER_ID
            AND A.MAGAZINE_ID = B.MAGAZINE_ID
            AND A.CHANGE_TIME = B.CHANGE_TIME
```

Comment: This has solved the problem - I had two duplicate values that are no longer present :) thank you very much. I realise now that my original script was getting the duplicates when I grouped by the new value - skipping this grouping and then joining it back to the original table where the IDs and timestamps are the same has worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT ch.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY CHANGED_TIME DESC) as seqnum
      FROM CUSTOMER_HISTORY ch
     ) ch
WHERE NEW_VALUE IN (3, 43) AND seqnum = 1;
```